# How do I show x axis labels in a Google LinChart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm trying out Google charts for rendering a line chart for my app. Things mostly work, I get the following:

[image: Chart Output]

The one remaining issue I have is that I am only getting a single x-axis label. (The 12:00).

I'd like to show more x-axis labels, so I tried adding a gridlines property:

```
    // Line chart visualization
    var myLine = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'LineChart',
        'containerId': 'line_div'
    });

    myLine.setOptions({
        'title': 'My Chart',
        lineWidth: 1,
        colors: ['#006600', '#FF0000'],
        vAxes: [
            {title: 'AAA', titleTextStyle: {color: '#000000'}}, // Left axis
            {title: 'BBB', titleTextStyle: {color: '#000000'}} // Right axis
        ],
        hAxis: {
            format: 'hh:mm',
            gridlines: {count: 20}
        },
        series: [
            {targetAxisIndex: 1},
            {targetAxisIndex: 0}
        ]
    });
```

But no luck, it still only displays one label and no x-axis gridlines.

How do I get more x-axis labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be how I was populating my DataTable. I was using:

```
dataTable.addColumn({type: 'date', label: 'Date'})
```

because in my thinking a new Date() is a date. Google charts has a different opinion, so what I needed to do was:

```
dataTable.addColumn({type: 'datetime', label: 'Date'})
```

and that sorted it.